# Thinking sphinx search returns nothing when multiple index files used on a single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Searching sometimes yields no results when my sphinx indices are separated into multiple files in one model.

The versions I'm using:

- Rails - 4.1
- Thinking Sphinx - 3.0.6
- Sphinx - 2.0.9

I have five indices on this model:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :incident, name: "incident_index_1" ... do
  indexes name
end

ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :incident, name: "incident_index_5" ... do
  indexes tags.name, as: :tag      
  indexes custom_fields_values.value, as: :custom
end
```

Searching separately, the queries return correct results:

```
Incident.search(conditions: { custom: "dd" })
Incident.search("some string")
```

However, combining the field-specific query with the generic query sometimes returns nothing:

```
Incident.search("some string", conditions: { custom: "dd" })
```

If "some string" is in the `tag` field (which is defined in the same index file), it works. If it is in the `name` field (which is defined in a different index file), it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm guessing that's not your entire index definition, going by the context provided - can you share everything in the index definition?

Comment: I added some more information. The entire definition is pretty long, and I'm not sure how relevant all of it is. In general, I have another 25 "has" attributes, all defined in each index, and another 15 "indexes" fields, spread out between the 5 index definitions.

Comment: Okay, so I guess what I'm keen to know is: do you expect both 'some string' to be in any field for a specific record, and 'dd' to be in the custom field for that same record? I don't think this is related to polymorphism, because you're going through a standard association (it's the inverse which is polymorphic).

Comment: @pat, yes, that's what I expect. So do you mean `custom_fields_values.value, as: :custom` is the standard association?

Comment: Yes. You're not using `customfieldable` in your index definition, and that is the polymorphic association.

Comment: Do you get the result you expect when searching just for 'some string'?

Comment: @pat, yes I do. I get correct results for both individually.

Comment: Are the fields that match these values in the same Sphinx index?

Comment: No, but when they are in the same index file, it works. What's going on here? I obviously lack understanding of sphinx's inner workings.

Comment: I updated the question to correctly reflect the problem I have. You're right, it had nothing to do with polymorphism.

Comment: To be honest, I thought Sphinx might behave how you're expecting it to - if the indices have the same document id (and if you're not using a custom offset, they will be), then they should be considered the same document, albeit with data in different indices. Perhaps something to raise with the Sphinx team?

Comment: OK, thanks for your advice. I asked this question: http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=13493.

Comment: I'm not part of sphinx as such, but answered as best I understand it over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As clarified via discussions on the Sphinx forums](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=13493), the issue here is that the fields are in different indices, and a Sphinx document (a record in an index, which in the Thinking Sphinx/Rails context is an ActiveRecord model instance) should only exist in *one* Sphinx index, not spread across several.

**Edit**

To complete the answer here in SO and make the question standalone, the index now looks like this:

```
(1..5).each do |ind|
  ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :incident, name: "incident_index_#{ind}" ... do
    where "incidents.id % 5 = #{ind - 1}"
    indexes ...
    has ...
end
```

Documents are thus equally distributed between five sphinx index files, without a document existing in more than one index file.